# Comparing 2 Object properties in a Class

Tags: c#, testing

I have a class Person which contains several properties. Multiple instances of this class are in an array PersonList.

Is it possible to compare properties of different instances of an object in an array?

For example : find out who is the oldest and who is the youngest ?

```
 public class Persoon
{
    public Persoon()
    {
    }

    //Properties maken
    public Persoon(string naam, Int16 gewicht, Int16 lengte, DateTime geboortedatum)
    {

        this.Naam = naam;
        this.Gewicht = gewicht;
        this.Lengte = lengte;
        this.Geboortedatum = geboortedatum;
    }




    public string Naam { get; set; } // AutoProperty

    public double Gewicht { get; set; } // AutoProperty

    public int Lengte { get; set; } // AutoProperty

    public DateTime Geboortedatum { get; set; } // AutoProperty

    public double BerekenBmi()
    {

        //BMI formule: Gewicht in kilogram / (Lengte in meter * Lengte in meter)
       return Math.Round(Gewicht/((Lengte/100.0) * (Lengte/100.0)),1);
    }

    public string BmiStadiumBerekenen()
    {


        if (BerekenBmi() < 18.5) return "ondergewicht";
        if (BerekenBmi() >= 18.5 && BerekenBmi() <= 24.9) return "normaal";
        if (BerekenBmi() >= 25 && BerekenBmi() <= 29.9) return "overgewicht";
        if (BerekenBmi() >= 30 && BerekenBmi() <= 34.9) return "obesitas I";
        if (BerekenBmi() >= 35 && BerekenBmi() <= 39.9) return "obesitas II";
        else return "morbide obesitas";


    }



    public int BerekenLeeftijd()
    {

        TimeSpan leeftijd = DateTime.Today - Geboortedatum;

        return (int) leeftijd.TotalDays;
    }


}
```

I need to compare the oldest and the youngest person so i can calculate the amount of time that is between them.. I've done this before with only 2 persons without arrays but now i need to do it with them.

Comment: Could you post at least your "class"? Perhaps some code on what you tried?

Comment: You can [iterate through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby.aspx) array/list/collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, and the solution is in your question! You have to use a compareTo() method.
You have to implement the compareTo() method in the class Person.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{...}
```

then you simply add the method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person p) {...}
```

This method want another Person object in the parameters, so you can choose the way to compare the people. For example you said that you want to compare the age of each Person, you have just to put an if close sentence inside the compareTo() method.

```
 int result;
    if (this.age < p.getAge()) {
        esito = -1;
    }
    else if(this.age = p.getAge()){
        esito = 0;
    }
    else{
        esito = 1;
    }
 return esito;
```

This method returns an int number: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Source:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

School lessons

:)

Comment: Thanks but its in csharp @marco

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this (using Linq):

```
var youngest = personList.OrderBy(p => p.Age).First();
```

(Noting that this assumes that there is seomthing in your list to start with).